# Float in css causing element to move down But when innerHTML changed by JS, it gets up

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a element

on my webpage, which shifts its position down when applied Float:left in stylesheet. But then, if I use javascript function to change inner html it goes up,and when float left is removed its obviously up. Dunno what the heck is going on, I am a rookie :P
Possible causes and suggestions ?

html code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function runonhover() {
        document.getElementById("sitename").innerHTML = "Run...!!";
    }
</script>

<div id="sitename" onmouseover="document.getElementById('sitename').innerHTML = 'Run...!!';">
    <p>FurryLife</p>
</div>
```

corresponding css is

```
#sitename {
    transition: transform 0.6s;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 45px;
    font-size: 56px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: chiller,serif;
    text-shadow: rgb(185,82,19) 3px 3px 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BY setting `document.getElementById('sitename').innerHTML = 'Run...!!';`
will set `Run...!!` and remove inner `<p></p> tag`. use `document.getElementById('sitename').innerHTML = '<p>Run...!!</p>';` it will not disturb your UI.

```css
#sitename {
    transition: transform 0.6s;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 45px;
    font-size: 56px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: chiller, serif;
    text-shadow: rgb(185, 82, 19) 3px 3px 3px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function runonhover() {
        document.getElementById("sitename").innerHTML = "Run...!!";
    }
</script>

<div id="sitename" onmouseover="document.getElementById('sitename').innerHTML = '<p>Run...!!</p>';">
    <p>FurryLife</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

By setting the innerHTML the `<p>` gets removed, while the `<p>` has some margin spacing, causing the element to move around.